# Fullcalendar v.4.2.0 display Quarterly by Year

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar

I have a requirement in a project in which I need to implement an event calendar to display Quarterly by Year. Currently [Fullcalendar.io](https://fullcalendar.io/docs) doesn't seem to cater this functionality. Also found one question regarding this by some folks but Arshaw (the creator) just closed it without further details here: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/2861

My goal is to display the events using Fullcalendar v4.2.0 in a quarterly manner per year. In case you got some work around please let me know. Thank you.

P.S. it will get integrated in angularjs (old but gold)

Comment: If you want some non-standard layout or time duration in your view then in general you need to make a [custom view](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-views) (either just from settings, or by creating a whole new plugin, depending on the complexity, and how far it deviates from the views already provided). Keep in mind however that it's not a simple task to create (and maintain) a new custom view plugin, so consider carefully whether how much you really need it, or whether you can find an alternative way to display the same information in a way that will be useful to yours users.

Comment: I found something like [Resource-Daygrid-View](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resource-daygrid-view) in custom view page.Seems promising. Under Resource[ ] would be (Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4). The real challenge is to filter dates under specific resource. Its a good start after all thank you.

Comment: resources are not intended to be related to specific dates, so you would always be working against the intended behaviour of the calendar - as you rightly say, filtering the dates would be a challenge, it would be hard to use any of fullCalendar's built-in features for fetching the correct events automatically by date, and so on. So you'd still have quite a bit of work to do to ensure it behaves properly. Also bear in mind that any resource-based views are a premium product for which you might need a paid license - see https://fullcalendar.io/license

Comment: If you're ok with the licensing, then I wonder if actually a Timeline view with a custom duration of 1 year and a custom slotDuration of 3 months might be easier to implement. You can use it without resources, if necessary, or you could take advantage of the ability to declare multiple resources if it's useful to you.

Comment: For the daygrid/resource idea, I can see that each resource could represent a quarter, but I'm not sure how you'd actually get events to show in the grid, since the grid has times of day in it, so events are supposed to have a date/time property related to the specific day in order to be displayed. I don't see how you'd work round that, to be honest - it's a fundamental feature of that type of view.

Comment: That's a good point. We'll see if I can sort it out. Thank you for your inputs.